# Probability of the number of calls in progress given the cdf of the length of the call

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Calls arrive according to Poisson process with parameter $$. Lengths of the calls are iid with cdf $F_x(x)$. What is the probability distribution of the number of calls in progress at any given time?

I am confused, is the answer then just the pdf of Poisson, that is, $P(X=x) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$?

I feel like I am missing something. I assumed the $$ is the number of the calls and I am not sure how to use this with the cdf of the lengths of the calls.

Comment: Hint: research Erlang distributions.

Comment: This is [queuing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory). 
Calls arrive may according to a Poisson process (rather than distribution) It can get complicated if the lengths of calls do not follow a nice specific  distribution

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach, without queuing theory.

Let $T>0$ be any given time, and take $\Big\{[t_{i-1},t_i),s_i\Big\}_{i=1}^n$ as any uniform tagged partition of $[0,T)$ with $\Delta t=\frac{t_i-t_{i-1}}{n}$.

When $n$ is very large, the number of customers that call the call center on $[t_{i-1},t_i)$ may be regarded as a splitting process$-$ those who remain on the line at time $T$ and those who hang up by time $T$. The former distribution is approximately $\text{Poisson}\left(\lambda \Delta t\left(1-F_X(T-s_i)\right)\right)$.

So, the *total* number of calls in progress at time $T$ is approximately $\text{Poisson}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda \Delta t\left(1-F_X(T-s_i)\right)\right)$

Taking $n$ to $\infty$ yields a desired distribution of $$\text{Poisson}\left(\int_0^T\lambda \left(1-F_X(T-t)\right)\mathrm{d}t\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You have an m/g/infinity queue. The distribution of the number of customers in that queue is known to be Poisson

See for instance Kleinrock book